# Print PDF with headless chrome in ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, pdf, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to print a pdf in ubuntu using chrome headless with this command line :

```
google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=gen2.pdf file:///home/user/Desktop/invoiceTemplate2.html
```

The file is generated, but **without any text** and all other styles are applied.

**And** when I print the same page HTML with chrome directly, it prints ok.

**And** I've tried to print the same file HTML on windows with headless chrome and it did print ok with the letters and all.

**And** when I try to print a HTML file but from the internet like :

instead of : `file:///home/user/Desktop/invoiceTemplate2.html`
I put : `http://www.google.com`

it prints OK with headless.

Any help will be apreciated, thx.

Comment: `file:///invoiceTemplate2.html` would imply that this file resides directly under `/` in linux imho, maybe that is not the correct path?

Comment: yeah i've changed that only for the pupose of the question, I'll edit it, but I put an image in the HTML file and I'm getting it in the printed PDF but not the text.

Comment: Actually it was a font problem, I was getting from google-font and I don't know why it didn't get it from the internet so I made it local and now the page prints successfully.