# Chrome Headless print-to-pdf using PDF file input

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to use Headless Chrome to re-print a pdf file from a pdf file.

Similar Post: [Print PDF with headless chrome in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791585/print-pdf-with-headless-chrome-in-ubuntu)

I've tried several variations of this:

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=E:/Python/Working/foo_flat3.pdf  file://E:/Python/Working/foo_flat2.pdf

chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=E:/Python/Working/foo_flat3.pdf  "E:/Python/Working/foo_flat2.pdf"
```

And no PDF file is generated. When I use a webpage, for example:

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=E:/Python/Working/foo_flat3.pdf  https://www.google.com/
```

It functions as intended, and "foo_flat3.pdf" is generated.

Why am I doing this? I'm trying to make use of Chrome's ability to unlock and flatten pdf files, as it is the fastest option I've found. If there's other options, I would be interested in those too.

Comment: @KJ I figured out how to use edge in headless mode (didn't get the path variable working, but oh well). However, I still can't start with a PDF file. It works for a website, but not a pdf file. Same as for chrome.

Comment: The bookmarks / hyperlinks is a downside when I'm flattening some documents so I can mark them up, but isn't a downside for general usage. 


Do you have a recommendation for something else that would work? I eventually want to be able to do bulk flattening.